# I can't click the ListView in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I made an app using contact sync. I list the following contact info with photo, name and number. I successfully list all those things in a custom **ListView**, but I can't click the **ListView**. It looks like locked, Unable to click it.

But I made a same procedure to another activity. Using custom **ListView** but I can click this view and it works fine.

What is the problem? here is my sample coding:

```
    ListView settingsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.manage_track_listView);
    ArrayList<ContactList> MySettingsList = new ArrayList<ContactList>();

    ContactList setting1 = new ContactList("contact name 1", "Number 1", null);
    ContactList setting2 = new ContactList("contact name 2", "Number 2", null);
    ContactList setting3 = new ContactList("contact name 3", "Number 3", null);

    MySettingsList.add(setting1);
    MySettingsList.add(setting2);
    MySettingsList.add(setting3);

    ContactList list[] = new ContactList[MySettingsList.size()];

    for(int i=0;i<MySettingsList.size();i++) {

        ContactList mySettings = MySettingsList.get(i);
        list[i] = new ContactList(mySettings.getName(), mySettings.getNumber(), mySettings.getImageIcon());
    }

    ContactListAdapter adapter = new ContactListAdapter(this, R.layout.manage_track_list_custom_view, list);
    settingsList.setAdapter(adapter);
    System.out.println("before listener");
    settingsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            System.out.println("Clicked " + position);
        }
    });
    System.out.println("after listener");
```

Here ContactList is a class which has contact name, number, and byte[] for imageBlob. If the image is null I set the default ic_launcher as a contact image. The adapter class is:

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactList> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ContactList objects[] = null;

    View row;

    public ContactListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ContactList[] objects) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.objects = objects; 
        System.out.println(objects[1].getName());
        System.out.println(objects[1].getNumber());
        System.out.println(objects[1].getImageIcon());
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        row = convertView;
        final ContactListHolder holder;

        if ( row == null ) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ContactListHolder();
            holder.image    = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.contactImage);
            holder.name     = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
            holder.number   = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.contactNumber);
            holder.check    = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.selectedContact);

            row.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ContactListHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        ContactList contact = objects[position];
        if(contact.imageIcon != null) {

            Bitmap imgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(contact.imageIcon, 0, contact.imageIcon.length);
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
        } else {

            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }

        holder.name.setText(contact.name);
        holder.number.setText(contact.number);
        holder.check.setChecked(objects[position].isSelected());    

        return row;

    }

    static class ContactListHolder {

        ImageView image;
        TextView name;
        TextView number;
        CheckBox check;
    }
}
```

I Have more than 100 contacts so added only 3 objects. In this contact list I successfully receive contact image, name, number.

What is the problem the **ListView** is unable to click? I hope any one of u will guide me. Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks to all. now got the result by just adding `android:focusable="false"` in my all child views. thanks for ur guidings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in nested Views, the child view always gets all the touch events first. if you want the parent view (in your case, the listView row), to get a touch event, you must return false on the child events or set them to be `android:clickable="false"` in the manifest.

Answer (score 8):

add

```
 android:focusable="false"
```

and

```
 android:clickable="false"
```

for each child view like imageview,textview,checkbox etc... of your row layout means in **manage_track_list_custom_view.xml**

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to set all your clickable things eg. checkboxes, buttons etc. as not focusable(in the adapter class).

```
        holder.yourButton.setFocusable(false);
        holder.yourButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

        holder.yourCheckbox.setFocusable(false);
        holder.yourCheckbox.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

When you add the listView, call

```
setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

Have a look [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414&can=1&q=listview&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) for more info.

Comment: I think this should be marked as the answer as this allows items inside a list view to be clicked at the same time as the list items themselves to receive events.

Answer (score 0):

You can set onclick listner to the View row in ContactListAdapter class.

```
    holder.check.setChecked(objects[position].isSelected());    
       row.setOnclickListner(new Onclicklistner(){
          // Your code here
       });
    return row;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem when I can't click on other part of an item in list view, just can click in textview or imageview inside that item. So I set my textview:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

my item like this:

```
<relative>
[image][textview]
relative/>
```

And clicking event worked fine because I click on the textview. Hope will help anyone has same problem.