# Click methods at custom ListView in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have the custom Listview.
there are two textboxes and a checkbox.
Xml files are added, too.

```
package com.example.phonebook;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

ListView lst;

CustomPerson p;

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
ImageView imageView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonSms, buttonCall, buttonPhoto;


    List<CustomPerson> list = new ArrayList<CustomPerson>();

    list = GetContacts();

    lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_person);
    buttonSms= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSms);
    buttonCall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCall);
    buttonPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnPhoto);


    lst.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),list));

    lst.setOnItemClickListener(this);

     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,       long id) {

    // I want to get name and number here
     Toast.makeText(this,"Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

 @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi" }) private List<CustomPerson> GetContacts()
{
    Intent intentContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); 
    List<CustomPerson> contactList = new ArrayList<CustomPerson>();

    Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(intentContact.getData(), null, null, null, null);      
       while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
       {          
           String Name = "";
           String PhoneNumber = "";
           String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
           Name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)); 

           String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

           if ( hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
               hasPhone = "true";
           else
               hasPhone = "false" ;

           if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
           {
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext()) 
            {
              PhoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            }
            phones.close();
           }

           contactList.add(new CustomPerson(Name, PhoneNumber));

      }          
       cursor.close();
       return contactList;
}
```

I have CustomPerson class and CustomAdapter.

When I click a person from listview, I want to get person's phone and number to my object p.
But these setOnItemClickListener and  OnItemClick methods don't work, because when I run the project, I can't click any items.

Comment: try to use lst.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this,list)); instead of getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem I think it's for the clickable checkbox. Try to follow this similar issue with a button on a listview resolved early here:

[I can't click the ListView in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203713/i-cant-click-the-listview-in-android)

Comment: when it is clicked, how can i get name or number? I try that    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
 p= (CustomPerson) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 
 String name= p.getName();
    }

Comment: you can set an onClickListener to the checkbox inside the getView method of the adapter and there you can obtain the position of the listview item.